# Overlays not showing up on top of data-generated d3 shapes

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, topojson

I am a noob with d3.js. I am using topoJSON data to render maps and so far it's been working great. Now I want to overlay some data such as text or circles on top of each country/region and I am hitting a wall. I have code similar to this:

```
var countries = g.append("g")
    .attr("id", "countries")
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(topojson.feature(collection, collection.objects.countries).features)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", path)
    .style("fill", colorize)
    .attr("class", "country")
    .on("click", clicked)
```

which properly renders my map. In order to overlay some circles on it, I do the following:

```
countries
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", function(d, i, j) {
      return 10; // for now
    })
    // getCentroid below is a function that returns the 
    // center of the poligon/path bounding box
    .attr("cy", function(d, i, j) { return getCentroid(countries[0][j])[0]})
    .attr("cx", function(d, i, j) { return getCentroid(countries[0][j])[1]})
    .style("fill", "red")
```

Which is pretty cumbersome (specially the way it accesses the countries array), but it succeeds at appending a circle for each path representing a country. The problem is that the circle exists in the SVG markup, but doesn't show up at all in the document. I am obviously doing something wrong, but I am at a loss of what is it.

Comment: Sounds like the coordinates are off. Did you check that? Remember that you need to project the centroid point to screen coordinates.

Comment: Manually editing the markup and putting the circle as the country path's sibling makes the circle visible (albeit with wrong coordinates indeed), but the circle disappears when is the country path's child. Also, how to project a circle into the proper coordinates, as opposed to a path?

Comment: Ah, I see -- `circle` elements can't be children of `path` elements. Will post an answer with more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're appending the `circle` elements to `path` elements, which you can't do in SVG. You need to append them to the parent `g` elements. The code would look something like this.

```
var countries = g.selectAll("g.countries")
  .data(topojson.feature(collection, collection.objects.countries).features)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("id", "countries");

countries.append("path")
  .datum(function(d) { return d; })
  .attr("d", path)
  // etc

countries.append("circles")
  // etc
```

Comment: That worked thanks. Now to figure out how to project the circles in the proper perspective and not make the later paths in the collection overlap some circles :)